# Is it possible to have the same Model and CGrid parameter in a form

Tags: yii

I have a form

```
$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array('id'=>'subject-form','enableAjaxValidation'=>false,));
```

which has a parameter "Subject"

```
$form->labelEx($model,'subject');
$form->textField($model,'subject',array('size'=>200,'maxlength'=>255));
```

I would also like to add a "Subject Search Grid" further down the view (so I can search other Subjects as I'm editing the current). To that end I am passing $model into the view as normal, plus an alias $relatives to the grid.

```
$subject_search_grid= $this->widget(
  'zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', 
  array(
        'id'=>'subject-grid',
        'dataProvider'=>$relatives->search(),
        'filter'=>$relatives,
        'columns'=>array(
            'id',
            'subject',
            array('class'=>'CButtonColumn',),
        ),  
  ), 
  $captureOutput=true
);
```

CGrid is working perfectly, however it's instance of 'subject' is overwriting the $form 'subject' when I try save or update the form. Is there any way of moving CGrid out of the view logic so it does not overwrite the value?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Place the gridview outside the form? So after `<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>`.